# Two identical XML layouts looks different in two projects Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have copied layout file from one project to another. In original project it looks like:[image]

But in the project I've copied the file to the layout looks like:[image]

These two XML are absolutely identical. Here is the code of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_filter"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_80"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearlayout_filter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_filters_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:text="Filters"
            android:textColor="@color/greyish_brown_two"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_filter_blue"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_reset"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/water_blue"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/filter_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/theme_bg"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_filters_heading" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandablelistview_filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_reset"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardview_apply"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_apply"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/applyFiltersBtn"
                style="@style/button_blue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="Apply" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What can cause the problem? How to make the layout in the second project look like the layout from the first one?

Comment: First, check the SDK version of the project, the librairies they are both using, check for any differences that could lead to this in the dependencies. You can also try to rebuild the project on both side, to get a fresh start. Maybe try to compile and send it to the emulator/device, to see if the difference are persisting.

Comment: @axel7083 yes, I had some thoughts about SDK and have already changed SDK of the second project but the layout hasn't changed. I changed Compile Sdk Version from 29 to 28 and Build Tools Version from 29.0.3 to 29.0.2. Can libraries affect on XML? I'm not quite sure they are the problem.

Comment: Oh, seems like libraries were really the problem. I copied all the dependencies from the original project and now it works as it supposed to do. Huge thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, you should also migrate to androidX because you will not be able to use SDK greater than 28 with the current librairie.

Answer (score 0):

you use wrong constraints import androidx library if you have not then use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alpha="1"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/white"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_filter"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearlayout_filter"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_filters_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
        android:text="Filters"
        android:textColor="@color/greyish_brown_two"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_filter_blue"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_reset"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/water_blue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/filter_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/theme_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_filters_heading" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandablelistview_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_reset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardview_apply"
        />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_apply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/applyFiltersBtn"
            style="@style/button_blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Apply" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

i hope it works for it.